# Issue after merging two objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, mirror, object-mode

[image][image]when I merge two objects, something happened to the first object.

actually, they are two different objects. when I join together 1st object shape has been changed that shown in second photo.

I used two modifiers 1. is Mirror and 2. Subdivision for both the objects.

Help me to move forward. give me solutions please.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which two objects and which is the first object? And what happened? Without knowing anything of this your screenshot looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If you've merged with an object that has some modifiers, the mesh that is joined will also have the modifiers effects

Comment: It looks as if you don't have 'Merge' checked in the unified object's _Mirror_ modifier, or the merge-threshold was more generous in the bonnet, before.